# Javascript - variable undefined when onload function runs

Tags: javascript, closures

```
for (var i=0, file; file=files[i]; i++) {
    if (file.type=='image/jpeg') {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            $('#upload_preview').append('<img src="'+e.target.result+'" width="150" alt="" />');
            alert(file.type); // error - file is undefined
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
}
```

Variable reader was declared within the code block where file was defined, yet the error reports variable file is undefined. this is driving me crazy, and I know it's something really basic.

Comment: You have a missing quote on the first line. Mistake?

Comment: Nah it's not that, I messed up there when I was simplifying the example.

Comment: @L84, Where did you declared file variable?

Comment: Can't say I'm an expert on js, but your onload function is called at a later point (i.e. after load). Isn't file out of scope then?

Comment: @Qiau It's in scope, and it could be set to `null` when the callback is executed, but then again it wouldn't say "undefined".

Comment: @Qiau: The function creates a closure that keeps file in scope, but I think you're on the right track in that the file reference gets modified somehow by the time the function gets called.

Comment: +1 indiv, as long as the handler is bound as in OP's example code, the handler function will have access to all variables in the outer scope. To enter in the `if` block which sets the handler, `file` must be defined so there must be an error somewhere else.

Comment: @KundanSinghChouhan in the for loop just above the code block I posted - `for (var i=0, file; file=files[i]; i++)` but should it matter? It's defined in that block, unless... the for loop is completed by the time onload event is fired?

Comment: As @indiv points out the file variable seems set to undefined in some parts of the code. Please show us the whole implementation otherwise its hard  to say whats wrong here.

Comment: L84, sure matter. The for.. loop must be not in the same closure.

Comment: @AndreasKöberle It's maybe 800 lines, mixed with HTML and PHP. I don't think it would clarify things much. I've added the outer for loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this loop `for (var i=0, file; file=files[i]; i++)` mention in the comments will set file to `undefined` in the last loop. You should use `each` or call a function in the for loop to save scope.

```
files.forEach(function(file){
if (file.type=='image/jpeg') {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
        $('#upload_preview').append('<img src="'+e.target.result+'" width="150" alt="" />');
        alert(file.type); // error - file is undefined
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
})
```

or if you need to support older browser:

```
for (var i=0, l=files.length; i < l; i++) {
    (function(i) {
        var file = files[i];
        if (file.type == 'image/jpeg') {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(e) {
                $('#upload_preview').append('<img src="' + e.target.result + '" width="150" alt="" />');
                alert(file.type); // error - file is undefined
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
    })(i);
}
```

Comment: Error: files.each is not a function. Also, it's undefined in every loop.

Comment: @L84:  The magic google keywords you want to search for are "javascript closure loop".  E.g., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Comment: Sorry must be `forEach` not `each`

Comment: as @indiv said, you'll be overwriting the `reader` var in each iteration if you don't use a closure, which the `forEach` creates. I just fail to see how OP's original `for` loop would have an undefined `file` in the last iteration. The conditional part `file=files[i]` would be false when `files[i]` is `undefined` right? Maybe I'm too sleepy.

Comment: Still the same error. Javascript doesn't even have a forEach, and when I used the jQuery $.each, there was still the original error (file is undefined)

Comment: Well, just goes to show I don't know jack about Javascript. Still, the error is `TypeError: files.forEach is not a function` so...

Comment: @FabrícioMatté the loop runs until the `file=files[i]` is falsy. So when it stops file muts be `undefined`

Comment: Yes I worded it 'til there. Now that you said it I realized that the `file` var in that scope will then be set to `undefined` and that will thrown an error when the onload handler executes. I see it clearly now.

Comment: @AndreasKöberle but see that alert() call, that should alert on every loop, not just the last one when it's undefined, right?

Comment: @L84 updated the answet with version older browser, that don't support `Array.forEach`

Comment: @AndreasKöberle Using Firefox 15.0 :) This is just too complicated, I'll mark your answer as accepted, maybe I'll go back to it in a couple of months when I understand any of this.

Comment: @L84 Nope. You're overwriting the `reader` with each iteration, so only the last one will still be in the memory. Using a closure such as the Andreas' updated answer should take care of that now.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté I didn't understand any of that. :) Thanks anyway, I'll skip this problem and come back to it some other time.

Comment: @L84 Well yeah, you can add [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) to your favorites for the next time you have a closure-related problem, by the 10~20th time you read all those answers you start to understand a bit about closures. `=]`